# Elixir GenServer no process

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, gen-server

I'm following [this tutorial](http://beyondscheme.com/2016/distributed-game-of-life-in-elixir)  and I've double and triple checked the code compared to the tutorial and their GH repo and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error when running `mix test`

I'm pretty green when it comes to Elixir so I'm not terribly good at debugging yet so please excuse me if this is super simple

[board_server.ex Gist](https://gist.github.com/Sparkmasterflex/9fbd275fbd84e8d1a0650b9dd2dbbe75)

[game_of_life.ex Gist](https://gist.github.com/Sparkmasterflex/3af5adde3d6b4b7d6314e30f699713fd)

And my test file

```
defmodule GameOfLife.BoardServerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest GameOfLife.BoardServer
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
test/board_server_test.exs:3
 ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call({:global, GameOfLife.BoardServer}, {:start_game, 1000}, 5000)
     ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
 stacktrace:
   (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:729: GenServer.call/3
   (for doctest at) lib/game_of_life/board_server.ex:121: (test)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you put the right module name in the `mod` key in `mix.exs`'s `application/0`?

Comment: In other words, you should post your `mix.exs` file.

Answer (score 0):

This error states that the server is not started. You can start it with the GameOfLife.BoardServer.start_link function.

In short, you should start your server with GenServer#start or GenServer#start_link functions.

[GenServer docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html)

Comment: So I have to start the server before running the tests? That's very different from Ruby

Comment: Your server is a process running all time and you communicate with it through message passing. As when you where doing with OOP, you can not pass a message to a class that has not been instantiated.

Comment: So I've tried running the `GameOfLife.BoardServer.start_game` and receive the same error as when I run the tests